# How to set permalink to fetch all children custom posts with parent post in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks

I create parent-child relationship for custom posts types.

> Generic : www.example.com/parent/parent_post
>
> Sample  : www.example.com/projects/project-one

In above URL parent is a custom post type and parent post is its single post.
I can show parents all posts and single post respectively as archive-parent.php and single-parent.php .

As I mentioned earlier, I create parent-child relationship and with child post that stores 'post_parent' as parent id.

> Generic : www.example.com/child/parent_post/child_post
>
> Sample  :
>   www.example.com/project_article/project-one/first-article

And for specific child post, URL will be as above.

Below code is for to get specific child post.And it's working fine.

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%child%', '([^/]+)', 'child=');
    add_permastruct('child', 'child/%parent%/%child%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?child=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );

function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'child' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
    $permalink = str_replace('%parent%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

> Generic : www.example.com/child/parent_post
>
> Sample  : www.example.com/project_article/project-one

Now I want all child posts with parent post, as in above URL.

I am new to word-press Please guide.

Comment: olden, but it works perfectly, have not tested it on wp 5.0. - https://github.com/codearachnid/wp-subordinate-post