# How to flush Global query variables in wordpress?

Tags: permalinks

I am using add_rewrite_rule() to show child posts for parent post.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/?','index.php?post_type=child&post_parent=$post_id','top');    
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'post_parent';
    return $vars;
}
```

Above code working fine, but change in **$post_id** doesn't effect **$var['post_parent']**.

I have to click save button of permalink every time for change in global variable.

Please guide me how to flush old **$var['post_parent']** varibale ?

Reason to use this approach i have to show all children posts for parent post.

Comment: If your rewrite rule is matching then where is the old value coming from? There should be nothing to flush. Perhaps a different rule is matching? Also `post_parent` is already a query var, you shouldn't have to add it, so your second filter is not needed

Comment: I have hard code value just for testing purpose as post_id for post_parent and it remains until i again click save button in permalink.

Comment: Not sure what saving permalinks has to do with this, perhaps you have expectations of what it should do that it isn't going to do without additional code, that you haven't outlined? A rewrite rule will have zero impact on the permalinks shown in the edit post screen and other UI, they're completely different systems. Any linkages or bridges you might think there are, they do not exist

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your rewrite rule:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/?','index.php?post_type=child&post_parent=$post_id','top');    
}
```

Instead of using the matched value, you've used `$post_id`. Since this isn't a double quoted string, and there is no `$post_id` variable, the value of `post_parent` will be the string literal `"$post_id"`, but `post_parent` expects a numeric post ID

Instead, [refer to the official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Basic_Usage) which uses this example, and even has a safer regular expression:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

So no, you don't need to flush the value because there is nothing to flush, that's not how rewrite rules work.

Finally, `post_parent` is already a query var, you don't need to add it a second time.

Comment: actually i can't use $matches[1] for this because i am using parent-child relationship and in database parent post name is not stored with child post instead it stored post_parent(id).

Comment: it's my another question regarding this please have a look on this also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313475/how-to-set-permalink-to-fetch-all-children-custom-posts-with-parent-post-in-word

Comment: Then I would advise against repurposing `parent_id` which already exists

Comment: Additionally, you must use `matches`, there is no other way to get the information out of the rewrite rule. Your problem would then be that you're misusing `post_parent`

Comment: I have update my code 
add_rewrite_rule('^child/([^/]+)/?','index.php?post_type=project_article&post_parent=$matches[1]','top');
but still didn't effect